# How to create second Tool Tip in checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, popup

The default tooltip in checkout/onepage/payment.phtml shows the pop for CVV security codes for credit cards.

We have another tooltip we need to display. However, I don't see an easy way to add another and get it to pop up. I have tried renaming "payment-tool-tip" and adding more javascript. I have tried renaming the second function. It's noto working for me. Can yo suggest something please?

Current tooltip:

```
<div class="tool-tip" id="payment-tool-tip" style="display:none;">
    <div class="btn-close"><a href="#" id="payment-tool-tip-close" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Close')) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Close') ?></a></div>
    <div class="tool-tip-content"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/cvv.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Card Verification Number Visual Reference')) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Card Verification Number Visual Reference')) ?>" /></div>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function toggleToolTip(event){
        if($('payment-tool-tip')){
            $('payment-tool-tip').setStyle({
                top: (Event.pointerY(event)-560)+'px'//,
                //left: (Event.pointerX(event)+100)+'px'
            })
            $('payment-tool-tip').toggle();
        }
        Event.stop(event);
    }
    if($('payment-tool-tip-close')){
        Event.observe($('payment-tool-tip-close'), 'click', toggleToolTip);
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

I want to add the following as a second tool tip that will also pop up upon clicking the new link on the page:

```
<div class="tool-tip" id="second-tool-tip" style="display:none;">
    <div class="btn-close"><a href="#" id="second-tool-tip-close" title="<?php echo $this->__('Close') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Close') ?></a></div>
    <div class="tool-tip-content"><p><strong>Second Tool Tip</strong><br />Second tool tip description.</p></div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding a second js function and changed 'payment-tool-tip' to 'second-tool-tip.' I also tried renaming a second js function to `toggleSecondToolTip` with 'second-tool-tip' to no avail. The second tool tip never pops up. Obviously, I'm not fluent in js.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

Your tooltip in `checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`

```
<div class="tool-tip" id="second-tool-tip" style="display:none;">
    <div class="btn-close"><a href="#" id="second-tool-tip-close" title="<?php echo $this->__('Close') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Close') ?></a></div>
    <div class="tool-tip-content"><p><strong>Second Tool Tip</strong><br />Second tool tip description.</p></div>
</div>
```

and script part in same file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function toggleToolTip(event){
        if($('payment-tool-tip')){
            $('payment-tool-tip').setStyle({
                top: (Event.pointerY(event)-560)+'px'//,
                //left: (Event.pointerX(event)+100)+'px'
            })
            $('payment-tool-tip').toggle();
        }
        Event.stop(event);
    }
    if($('payment-tool-tip-close')){
        Event.observe($('payment-tool-tip-close'), 'click', toggleToolTip);
    }

    function toggleSecondToolTip(event){
        if($('second-tool-tip')){
            $('second-tool-tip').setStyle({
                top: (Event.pointerY(event)-515)+'px'//,
                //left: (Event.pointerX(event)+100)+'px'
            })
            $('second-tool-tip').toggle();
        }
        Event.stop(event);
    }
    if($('second-tool-tip-close')){
        Event.observe($('second-tool-tip-close'), 'click', toggleSecondToolTip);
    }

    $$('.cvv-what-is-this-second').each(function(element) {
        Event.observe(element, 'click', toggleSecondToolTip);
    });

    initWhatIsCvvListeners();   
//]]>
</script>
```

**And obviously you need to have a clickable text in your payment method.**
Add this line:

```
<a href="#" class="cvv-what-is-this"><?php echo $this->__('What is this?') ?></a>
<a href="#" class="cvv-what-is-this-second"><?php echo $this->__('Second tooltip?') ?></a>
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you, but, unfortunately, it did not work. The first tool tip still works as usual, but nothing with the second one.

Comment: It works in my side, have tested already. Remember `cvv-what-is-this-second` is very important in order to get it work.

Comment: I wish you were on "this side." :)
I have tried this in version 1.9.2.1 and 1.9.2.2 on one server and in 1.9.2.2 on another server with no luck. I have tried it exactly as you have it in two different custom themes, the default theme, and rwd theme.

Comment: Did u add this exactly same? <a href="#" class="cvv-what-is-this"><?php echo $this->__('What is this?') ?></a> <a href="#" class="cvv-what-is-this-second"><?php echo $this->__('Second tooltip?') ?></a>

Comment: Yes. I tried exactly that. They are normally in separate divs, but I did as you have it (side by side) just to be exact, and it did not work. I also switched to default theme and added these to the default folders, and still nothing.

Comment: When you added, did this text `Second tooltip?` appeared? and also you can do inspect element and check if that added js part also called. Sometime phtml file could be wrong.